# Web API which enables Access-Control-Allow-Origin to *

Tags: javascript, cors, webapi

I could not find many open web API which allows CORS.

For example, https://docs.pullstring.com/docs/api does but most web API prohibits resource sharing over cross domains.
Some Web API support jsonp and rarely allows CORS.
I don't want to set up proxy server just to avoid CORS limitation.

Can anyone suggest list of available web API where CORS from any domains is allowed?

I think such api should be useful to learn new web app technologies and help web developers try them on it.

Comment: are you check if with this complement of chrome you can develop with apis? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog

Comment: Thank you for suggesting. It surely solves a part of the issue. Some issues still remain like running on mobile browser though.